# how to pop show exact right click event location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps-api-3

i have following code but my Pop does not show exact location of my right click how do this please help. how to pop show on my right click exact location

```js
  function openPopup() {
             //document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'block';
             $('#test').fadeIn(1000);
         }

         function closePopup() {
             //document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'none';
             $('#test').fadeOut(500);
         }
 google.maps.event.addListener(_map, "rightclick", function (event) {
                 openPopup();
             });
```

```css
    
      .popup {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
 bottom:0px;
   
    padding:10px;
    background-color:rgb(240,240,240);
    border:2px solid grey;
    z-index:100000000000000000;
}
    
.cancel {
    display:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin:0;
    float:right;
    height:10px;
    width:14px;
    padding:0 0 5px 0;

    z-index:100000000000000000;
}

.cancel:hover {
    background:rgb(255,50,50);
}
```

```html
  <div id="test" class="popup" style="display:none;">
    This is a test message
    <div class="cancel" onclick="closePopup();"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Where do you even get the click coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create a new pop up box for that, you can do this with google's `google.maps.InfoWindow` class

Use this

```
var map;
var markers   =   [];
var latalng   =   {lat:26.912082488274702, lng:75.81622123718262}
var infowindow;
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: latalng,
      zoom: 17
    }); 


   //infoWindow Object
   infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  //add event to right click    
  map.addListener('rightclick', function(event) {   
    //Set content to show on popup     
      infowindow.setContent("Your Messaage To show");   

    //get the position form google.maps.MouseEvent class passed in event objevc
      var latLang = { lat: event.latLng.lat(),lng:event.latLng.lng()};  

    //set the position of popup(infowindow)
      infowindow.setPosition(latLang);

    //open infowindow
     infowindow.open(map, this);
}); 

}
```